# How do I get around stream_select failing on "filtered" http streams?

Tags: php, http, stream

I am attempting to do a `stream_select` on a `fopen()`'d http stream. However, `stream_select` keeps giving me these errors and the select fails.

```
Warning: stream_select(): cannot cast a filtered stream on this system
Warning: stream_select(): cannot cast a filtered stream on this system
Warning: stream_select(): cannot cast a filtered stream on this system
Warning: stream_select(): No stream arrays were passed
```

The stream is created as this:

```
$ctx = array(..) // valid context, data is returned ok.
$fh = fopen($url,'r',NULL,$ctx);
// Result: resource(70) of type (stream)
```

So, what exactly is a filtered stream, why is the http stream considered such, and is there any way to get around it? The documentation for `stream_select` says that "Some streams can not be selected, such as zlib" but there is nothing mentioned about http.

**Edit**: After conversing with Google and the PHP documentation I tried to query the metadata from the stream to see if any filters were specified, and the answer is no: There is no `filters` index in the metadata which would indicate that this stream is filterless.

```
array(10) {
  ["wrapper_data"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "HTTP/1.1 200 Content Follows"
    [1]=>
    string(35) "Date: Wed, 03 Oct 2012 16:14:01 GMT"
    ...
    [9]=>
    string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
  }
  ["wrapper_type"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["stream_type"]=>
  string(14) "tcp_socket/ssl"
  ["mode"]=>
  string(1) "r"
  ["unread_bytes"]=>
  int(2447)
  ["seekable"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["uri"]=>
  string(17) "http://domain.tld/"
  ["timed_out"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["blocked"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["eof"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: Here's a wild guess: could these http streams be `transfer-encoding:chunked` and had the "unchunk" filter silently added to them by php 5.3+?

Comment: Hmm `curl -vvv` indicates that the `transfer-encoding` is `chunked`. The header is completely missing from the stream metadata however. Very confusing.

Comment: Do you get a different result when forcing http 1.0? (`curl -0vvv`)

Comment: Interestingly sending a http 1.0 request gives a http 1.1 response, and the `transfer-encoding` still comes out as `chunked`.

Comment: Can we see `$ctx`? (i.e. your context settings)

Comment: They are the bare essentials:
`$sopts = array('http' => array('method' => 'GET'));`

Comment: I have a similar issue, any solutions to this problem?